# Issue with arduino and ROS after creating a new message

Tags: ros, arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting creation of publisher failed: Checksum does not match
I am getting creation of subscriber failed: Checksum does not match

This error comes when we make a new arduino message and then do catkin_make and try to publish without flashing the arduino and changing the MD5.

I was struck at this problem since 1 day as I was trying to edit the MD5 in the header to match the checksum.

Solution:

1)copy the MD5 from the error you get to the header file
2)catkin_make
3)flash the arduino

I am a new user and this is a workaround  which i found. if anyone has better solution please suggest

I have put this up in case someone gets struck in the same problem can find the solution

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255630/issue-with-arduino-and-ros-after-creating-a-new-message/) by [angshumanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/27547/angshumang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The MD5 sum in the message definition is how ROS checks that message formats match. Messages with MD5 sums that don't match don't have the same format or the same serialization, and if you try to force them to be used together by editing the MD5 sums to match, you will get garbled or corrupt data.

If you change the message definitions that are used by your arduino, you should run make_libraries.py to regenerate the ROS arduino libraries, and then rebuild your arduino project and flash it again.

And as you already know, if you change the message definitions you also need to run catkin_make to recreate C++ and python libraries and recompile anything that uses them on the host side.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angshumanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/27547/angshumang/) on 2017-02-27**:
I am getting the error on running rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py

```
make_libraries.py generates the Arduino rosserial library files.  It 
requires the location of your Arduino sketchbook/libraries folder.

rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <output_path>
```

**Comment by [angshumanG](https://answers.ros.org/users/27547/angshumang/) on 2017-02-27**:
I got it . I was not putting the period after the command

```
 rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .
```